# Why I am getting "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars error" in python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I know that my program will work if I use

```
int(red)+int(blue)+int(green)
```

But I want to know why?

Here in my code I am adding `red`, `blue`, and `green` to `avg` (I declared as `avg=1000`), which can easily hold the sum of three 8-bit Integers.

I don't understand why it throws an overflow error.

Here is my code:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
avg=1000
img=cv.imread('C:/Users/#####/Documents/roi.jpg')
print(img.shape)
print(img.dtype)
for i in range(0,279):
    for j in range(0,449):
        blue=img[i,j,0]
        green=img[i,j,1]
        red=img[i,j,2]
        avg=(red+green+blue)/3
        img[i,j,0]=avg
        img[i,j,1]=avg
        img[i,j,2]=avg
while(1):
    cv.imshow("Image",img)
    if cv.waitKey(0):
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte\_scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384435/runtimewarning-overflow-encountered-in-ubyte-scalars)

Comment: no,I just want know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing the `type` of `red`, `green`, and `blue` and you'll get:

```
<class 'numpy.uint8'>
```

which has a maximum value of 255 each (see [Numpy Data Types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)).

Try printing the values of `red`, `green`, and `blue` and the sum of those three can easily exceed 255 (ex. 251 + 251 + 251). Yes, the `avg` variable will be typed as Python's native `int` which can hold the sum, but the warning is raised by the addition operation of the three `numpy.uint8` types, *before* the assignment to `avg`. You can check this by just doing

```
red + green + blue
```

without assigning it to anything, and it will raise the same warning.

Numpy's Data Types docs also provides some info on [Overflow Errors](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors):

> The fixed size of NumPy numeric types may cause overflow errors when a value requires more memory than available in the data type.